# How to include some variables inside static class?

Tags: php

I have a sql.php config file:

```
$GLOBALS["hostname_con1"] = 'localhost';
$GLOBALS["database_con1"] = 'mydatabase';
$GLOBALS["username_con1"] = 'root';
$GLOBALS["password_con1"] = '';
```

and I have a Config.php file

```
class Config{   

    public static $dbname = ''; // Your database name
    public static $dbuser = ''; // Your database username
    public static $dbpass = ''; // // Your database password
    public static $dbhost = ''; // Your database host, 'localhost' is default.
... many other variables...

}
```

This class.config is ONLY filled with static variables.

My Goal is to use the sql.php inside the Config.php to avoid redeclare twice.

I tried:

1) "include": gives an error !

2) public static $dbname = $GLOBALS["hostname_con1"]; error

3) I tried a constructor: but constructor is never called since Config.php is never instantiated.

What is the solution to use sql.php inside Config.php ?

Comment: Good idea to define those values only once. But what do you need the file `sql.php` for? Typically you just have a single definition. If it is a class or precedural does not matter. What certainly is a _really_ bad idea is to expose the database credentials as globals... But to answer your question: `public static $dbname = GLOBALS['database_con1'];`

Comment: No : look at 2) IT GIVES AN ERROR !!!

Comment: Define the credentials just inside the class. That is all you need. You access the credentials either by instantiating an object, or, if you define the credentials as static constants, in static manner.

Comment: Infact the Config.php is a HUGE file that is used for admin part. In other parts of the site, I don't want to LOAD IT: just sql.php !

Comment: Well, then create your static class inside sql.php, does not matter. But it clearly should _not_ be global vars! Then, in the huge config class you can instantiate an instance or access the credentials as shown below in the answer I wrote.

Comment: The error mentioned above probably is the result of the simple fact that you did not require or include the file `sql.php`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many alternatives for this, but since you ask for a "static class" I suggest this:

```
class DbConfig{   
    const NAME = 'mydatabase';
    const USER = 'root';
    const PASS = '';
    const HOST = 'localhost';
}
```

Now you can access the credentials in a static manner wherever you need to:

```
DbConfig::NAME
DbConfig::USER
DbConfig::PASS
DbConfig::HOST
```

In addition, what I like to do since it makes me feel better (note: this does not *really* add better security, it just looks like): I include the file declaring this static class by means of auto prepend in my http servers host configuration. That way no one sees where the file is located.

Oh, and by the way: you really should not use the root account for normal database operations. And especially you should not leave it configured without a password...

Comment: This just ADDs a 3rd file to 2  I have already. Maybe you should explain what I also should change in sql.php and Config.php

Comment: that is the better way.

Comment: @yarek why do you wanna do this ?

Comment: Why a third file? Just put it into `sql.php` instead of those global vars, if you really want to keep it separate.

Comment: Now I have DBConfig, sql.php and Config.php
You don't explain me what should be changed in sql.php or Config.php

Comment: Yes I did. Read my last comment. That also is what I asked right in my first command to your question: what do you need the file `sql.php` for. You did not answer to that. Maybe you want to explain now?

Comment: Problem is I need to change now ALL Config::dbname etc to DbConfig::name 
That is exactly I want to avoid. It works for sql.php, but What changes do I need to Config.php since public static $dbname = DbConfig::Name; gives an error